# Vector subscript out of range in my (unfinished) snake game

Tags: c++, vector

So I'm making a snake game(it's not finished) and I got the vector subscript out of range error. I'm really new to C++ and also very confused. It doesn't say where the error is(it's not in the error list)
and the error only shows up at runtime. Since I don't know where the problem is, here is the whole code.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "windows.h" 
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void up(int& direction)
{
    direction = 1;
}
void left(int& direction)
{
    direction = 2;
}
void down(int& direction)
{
    direction = 3;
}
void right(int& direction)
{
    direction = 4;
}
struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    vector<point> snek;
    snek.push_back({ 10,10 });
    snek.push_back({ 10,9 });
    snek.push_back({ 10,8 });
    snek.push_back({ 10,7 });
    char move;
    int direction=2;
    char board[20][20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
    while (true)
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
        case 1:
            for (unsigned int i = 1; i < (snek.size() - 1); i++)
            {
                snek[snek.size() - (i - 1)] = snek[snek.size() - i];
            }
            snek[0] = { (snek[0].x - 1),snek[0].y };
        case 2:
            for (unsigned int i = 1; i < (snek.size() - 1); i++)
            {
                snek[snek.size() - (i - 1)] = snek[snek.size() - i];
            }
            snek[0] = {snek[0].x ,(snek[0].y-1) };
        case 3:
            for (unsigned int i = 1; i < (snek.size() - 1); i++)
            {
                snek[snek.size() - (i - 1)] = snek[snek.size() - i];
            }
            snek[0] = {( snek[0].x + 1),snek[0].y};
        case 4:
            for (unsigned int i = 1; i < (snek.size() - 1); i++)
            {
                snek[snek.size() - (i - 1)] = snek[snek.size() - i];
            }
            snek[0] = {snek[0].x ,(snek[0].y+1) };
        }
        for (unsigned int i = 1; i < (snek.size() - 1); i++)
        {
            snek[snek.size() - (i - 1)] = snek[snek.size() - i];
        }
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (20 - 1); i++)
        {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            {
                cout << board[i][j];
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        move = _getch();
        switch (move) 
        {
        case 'w':
            up(direction);
            Sleep(1);
            break;
        case 'a':
            left(direction);
            Sleep(1);
            break;
        case 's':
            down(direction);
            Sleep(1);
            break;
        case'd':
            right(direction);
            Sleep(1);
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT: I rewrote my program completely and now it works fine. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "windows.h" 
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

void goTo(point p,vector<point>& snek)
{
    bool flag=false;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < snek.size(); i++)
    {
        if (p.x == snek[i].x && p.y == snek[i].y)
        {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    for (int i=snek.size()-1; i >0; i--)
    {
        if (!flag)
        {
            snek[i] = snek[i - 1];
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    snek[0] = p;
}
void makeFood(point& apple, vector<point> snek)
{
    bool appleValid = true;
    apple.x = (rand() % 19) + 1;
    apple.y = (rand() % 19) + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < snek.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        if (apple.x == snek[i].x && apple.y == snek[i].y)
        {
            appleValid = false;
        }
    }
    if (!appleValid)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        makeFood;
    }

}
int main()
{
    vector<point> snek;
    snek.push_back({ 10,10 });
    snek.push_back({ 10,9 });
    snek.push_back({ 10,8 });
    snek.push_back({ 10,7 });
    char move = 'w';
    string board[21][21];
    int direction=2;
    point apple;
    apple.x = rand() % 20;
    apple.y = rand() % 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = "  ";
        }
    }
    while (true)
    {
        bool loss=false;
        int highscore=0;
        bool  appleEaten = false;
        srand(time(NULL));
        if (snek[0].x == 0 && snek[1].x == 1)
            loss = true;
        if (snek[0].x == 20 && snek[1].x == 19)
            loss = true;
        if (snek[0].y == 0 && snek[1].y == 1)
            loss = true;
        if (snek[0].y == 20 && snek[1].y == 19)
            loss = true;
        if (loss)
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "You lost with a score of " << snek.size() - 4 << endl;
            system("PAUSE");
        }
        Sleep(100);
        if (_kbhit())
        {
            move = _getch();
        }
        system("CLS");
        switch (move) 
        {
        case 'w':
            goTo({ (snek[0].x - 1),snek[0].y }, snek);
            Sleep(10);
            break;
        case 'a':
            goTo({ snek[0].x ,(snek[0].y - 1) }, snek);
            Sleep(10);
            break;
        case 's':
            goTo({ (snek[0].x + 1),snek[0].y }, snek);
            Sleep(10);
            break;
        case'd':
            goTo({ snek[0].x ,(snek[0].y + 1) }, snek);
            Sleep(10);
            break;
        }
        board[apple.x][apple.y] = " 0";
        for (int k = 0; k < snek.size() - 1; k++)
        {
            board[snek[k].x][snek[k].y] = " *";
            board[snek[snek.size() - 1].x] [snek[snek.size() - 1].y] = "  ";
        }
        if (apple.x == snek[0].x && apple.y == snek[0].y)
        {
            snek.push_back({snek[snek.size()-1].x+1,snek[snek.size() - 1].y});
            appleEaten = true;
        }
        if (appleEaten)
        {
            makeFood(apple,snek);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            board[0][i] = "--";
            board[20][i] = "--";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            board[i][0] = '|';
            board[i][20] = '|';
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 21; j++)
            {
                cout << board[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "Score: " << snek.size() - 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Run your program with a debugger to localize the error

Comment: Your loops are identical. Have you considered writing a function to "shift" the snake?

Comment: Yes, But I didn't want to have to make that many references honestly

Comment: @Odysseus "Unhandled exception at 0x79F5F2F6 (ucrtbased.dll) in Source2.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal. occurred "
was the error  for the code snek[snek.size() - (i - 2)] = snek[snek.size() - i];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        for (unsigned int i = 1; i < (snek.size() - 1); i++)
        {
            snek[snek.size() - (i - 1)] = snek[snek.size() - i];
        }
```

That loop starts at i=1. So you try to write to snek[snek.size()], which is memory one **after** your vector's memory.

Using at() for non time-critical access to a vector (or container in general) would be nice too.

Answer (score 1):

You have the loop

```
for (unsigned int i = 1; i < (snek.size() - 1); i++)
{
    snek[snek.size() - (i - 1)] = snek[snek.size() - i];
}
```

At the very first iteration, when `i == 1`, then `snek[snek.size() - (i - 1)]` will be equivalent to `snek[snek.size() - (1 - 1)]` which is `snek[snek.size() - 0]` which is `snek[snek.size()]` which of course is out of bounds.

Comment: So should then what should I do? I want it to change snek[4] to snek[3] and so on.

Comment: @PolarBear you're jumping from 1 indexed to 0 indexed and getting yourself confused about the allowed ranges... you can just use 0 indexed and then life becomes much easier

Comment: Ok so I should do
for (unsigned int i; i<(snek.size - 1); i++)

Comment: @PolarBear Tip: do you need to move *all* the snek pieces? The only ones that actually change are snek end (no more snek there) and snek start (new snek piece here). If you remove the last element from vector and insert one at the front, you don't have to move anything.

Comment: I think so? Because I need to move the tail too?
I'm not sure TBH

Comment: @PolarBear `for (unsigned int i = 0; i < snek.size(); i++)`

Comment: @UKMonkey I just tried that and it gave the same error
or I just didn't do it for all of the loops im going to check again

Comment: I think I have to keep the 
` (snek.size-1)`

Comment: what if I did     for (unsigned int i = 2; i < (snek.size()+2); i++)?

Comment: @PolarBear Rewrite your program with the knowledge that indices start at 0 and stick with that.  You are falling into the trap that I see most new programmers get into when trying to fake 1-based arrays.  Off-by-one errors, underflowing into index 0, etc.  If you want to show to the user 1-based output, then do that only when outputting information.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie my whole program?

Comment: @PolarBear You dug yourself a hole when you went down the 1-based array trap.  You now do not know if or where any off-by-one bugs are lurking.  So honestly yes, rewrite your program.  If you look at your code now, it looks like a patchwork of fixes and non-fixes, all due to the aspect of you using 1-based arrays.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I completely rewrote my program and it works!